# Why is this Singleton Location Manager class returning a nil Location?

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I am trying to use the below `LocationSingleton` `Class` from this [blog](https://bestpractiseios.blogspot.com/2017/01/global-locationmanager-singleton-class.html?showComment=1528096667133#c7782944110802258286) in my project. I like the simplicity of its usage.

You start updating location by simply calling:

```
LocationSingleton.sharedInstance.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Get the last location by simply calling:

```
LocationSingleton.sharedInstance.lastLocation
```

My intention is to start location services, get the last location so that I can then fetch users from Firebase using the location returned.

**The issue is that if I call `lastLocation` straight after** `startUpdatingLocation` it returns `nil`.

After some debugging I've found the reason is because location services are slow to start on the device and therefore when `lastLocation` is called the devices hasn't acquired the location yet. **I would like to execute the next command as soon as the `lastLocation` has been recorded. How can I achieve that?**

I would like to understand how the `Protocol` is being used?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

protocol LocationServiceDelegate {
    func locationDidUpdateToLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation)
    func locationUpdateDidFailWithError(error: NSError)
}

class LocationSingleton: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var lastLocation: CLLocation?
    var delegate: LocationServiceDelegate?

    static let sharedInstance:LocationSingleton = {
        let instance = LocationSingleton()
        return instance
    }()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        guard let locationManagers=self.locationManager else {
            return
        }

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            //locationManagers.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManagers.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            //            locationManagers.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        locationManagers.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManagers.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManagers.distanceFilter = 0.1
        locationManagers.delegate = self

    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        self.lastLocation = location
        updateLocation(currentLocation: location)

    }

    @nonobjc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .restricted:
            // restricted by e.g. parental controls. User can't enable Location Services
            break
        case .denied:
            // user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }



    // Private function
    private func updateLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation){

        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }

        delegate.locationDidUpdateToLocation(currentLocation: currentLocation)
    }

    private func updateLocationDidFailWithError(error: NSError) {

        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }

        delegate.locationUpdateDidFailWithError(error: error)
    }

    func startUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Starting Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        //        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

    func stopUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Stop Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() {
        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

}
```

Comment: Of course it's `nil` because retrieving the location works asynchronously. Use the delegate methods or a completion handler. By the way there is much redundant code. Declare the shared instance just: `static let sharedInstance = LocationSingleton()`. Declare the `LocationManager` as constant and non-optional: `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` and delete the corresponding lines in `init`. And this is Swift. Rather than `guard let delegate = self.delegate else { return }; delegate.locationDidUpdate...` just write `delegate?.locationDidUpdate...` without the `guard` statement.

Comment: lastlocation when you first called nil because you made the declaration
"var lastLocation: CLLocation?" as default
the declaration clearly produces "lastLocation = nil"

as an illustration:
startUpdatingLocation () -> get location -> when finished will go to "didUpdateLocations delegate" here you just enter lastLocation = location

as a note when call startUpdatingLocation () location is not directly found because there is a delay that duration depends on the network

Comment: @vadian thank you for the feedback this is great, I was hoping if you're able amend the code with your suggestions and repost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location manager works asynchronously and provides delegate methods to get the result.

In your class adopt `LocationServiceDelegate`, implement the delegate methods and set the delegate for example in `viewDidLoad`

```
func locationDidUpdateToLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation)
{
    print(LocationSingleton.sharedInstance.lastLocation)
}

func locationUpdateDidFailWithError(error: NSError)
{
    print(error)
}

func viewDidLoad()
    super viewDidLoad()

    let locationSingleton = LocationSingleton.sharedInstance
    locationSingleton.delegate = self
    locationSingleton.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

When a location is detected, one of the delegate methods is called